# Domino question from SU

Tags: discussion, migration

I was wondering if you were interested in [this Lotus Domino question](https://superuser.com/questions/377584/extract-private-key-from-domino-keyring) from Super User.  It seems fairly well written (though I don't know much about Domino) and seems to be a better fit for SF with its many questions about Domino.

On a side note, I've noticed that SF has [domino](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/domino) and [lotus-domino](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lotus-domino) - perhaps a synonym is in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little old, but sure.  I know nothing about Domino though so don't expect me to be of any help answering it :-)

Comment: Cool, I pinged the OP and he's still looking for an answer.  So I'll let this meta question stew for a little while to see if anyone objects, and flag for migration if not.

Comment: no need to stew - go ahead and move it.

Comment: @dsolimano you can move it over - worst that will happen is everyone eyes it funny and backs away because it's Domino.